# Delete dupes without deleting data loaded multiple times

Tags: sql, db2

I have mistakenly loaded duplicate files into a database table (IBM DB2 v9.7). I need to delete the duplicate records without deleting valid data.

Initially, I though of `HAVING count(*) > 1` as the solution to my problem but this will not work. Our supplier produces parts with modified specs so a file may be loaded more than once with valid data.

I know a few things:

1. the date range for my duplicate records: between '2012-08-27' and
   '2012-09-02'
2. the attributes to use to validate data

This is my SQL code to identify the dupes:

```
SELECT CAST(ENDDATE AS DATE) ENDDATE,CAST(LOADEDON AS DATE),SUBSTR(SITEID,1,20) SITEID,SUBSTR(LOCATIONNAME_1,1,20),SUBSTR(RID,1,15),COUNT(RID) FROM AUTOMATION WHERE CAST(ENDDATE AS DATE) BETWEEN '2012-08-27' AND '2012-09-02' GROUP BY CAST(ENDDATE AS DATE),CAST(LOADEDON AS DATE),SUBSTR(SITEID,1,20),SUBSTR(LOCATIONNAME_1,1,20),SUBSTR(RID,1,15) ORDER BY 5 ASC FOR FETCH ONLY WITH UR
```

EDIT: set of columns that can be used to specify a duplicate are RID,LOADEDON and FILENAME (not shown here).

This is a sample output

```
08/29/2012 09/05/2012 JGS Memphis          JGS Memphis          029369751671            518
09/01/2012 09/05/2012 Reynosa              Reynosa              029054883474            521
08/29/2012 09/05/2012 JGS Memphis          JGS Memphis          028881223425            522
```

I want to delete all the duplicate records in the timeframe '2012-08-27' AND '2012-09-02' without deleting the records that are loaded N times for legit reasons.

Note: the table does not have a primary key (like `Rowid` in MS Sqlserver, for instance)

Comment: Can't you just do a rollback?

Comment: Caught the error this morning. It happened last week. I was too late.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't quite tell which set of columns specifies a duplicate.  The following assumes that it is the columns in your sample output:

```
delete from (select t.*,
                    row_number() over (partition by enddate, loadedon, siteid order by loadedon desc) as seqnum
             from automation t
            ) t
where seqnum > 1
```

This uses row_number() to assign sequential numbers and deletes all but the first row, guaranteeing that one stays in the database.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you have some way to tell the difference between a record that is completely identical to some other record record, but is good, and a record that is also completely identical to some other record, but isn't good, then there really isn't any way to do that.  Or did I miss something in the question?